# Minus a day from date in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, performance, nosql, nosql-aggregation

I want MongoDB query to minus a day from existing date in a column and update the same.

query to update a date like
original date = '2024-12-24T18:30:32'
updated date = '2024-12-23T18:30:32'
and how to execute the query on terminal also....?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the terminal and use `mongosh` command to login to DB as below:

```
mongosh "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster_name>.example.mongodb.net"
```

Connect to appropriate DB using `show dbs` and `use <db_name>` command. And use `$dateSubtract` expression as below:

```
db.collection.update({
    "_id": ObjectId("<dummy_id>")
},
[
    {
    $set: {
        date: {
            $dateSubtract: {
                startDate: "$date", // ISODate("2024-12-24T18:30:32"),
                unit: "day",
                amount: 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Syntax in general for `$dateSubtract` is:**

```
{
    $dateSubtract: {
        startDate: <Expression>,
        unit: <Expression>,
        amount: <Expression>,
        timezone: <tzExpression>
    }
}
```

Refer below links for more details:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/mongo/#start-the-mongo-shell-and-connect-to-mongodb

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateSubtract/

Comment: This could be improved by including the use of the `$set` operator to demonstrate the update in an example [like this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KcFO8gROaJc) perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [pipeline update](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) to achieve this, like so:

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": 1
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "date": {
        $subtract: [
          "$date",
          1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 //one day in milliseconds
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z9UNI3iH6za)